# php multidimensional array ternary statement syntax

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, multidimensional-array, ternary

```
//  $vote_table[index]['voter_meta']['name'] is the key to sort by.

usort( $vote_table, function( $a, $b ){
 return ($a['voter_meta']['name'] == $b['voter_meta']['name'])
  ? 0
  : ( ($a['voter_meta']['name'] < $b['voter_meta']['name'])
   ? -1
   : 1
  );
});
```

What is the error in the syntax?

Comment: Well, what is the error message?

Comment: There is an error in the syntax and i dont know enough ternary statements to find it. I dont know if its a semi-colon or what...

Answer (score 0):

You had problem with a bracket , here is the correct version of your code :

```
 usort( $vote_table, function( $a, $b ){

     return ($a['voter_meta']['name'] == $b['voter_meta']['name'])
     ? 0  
     : ($a['voter_meta']['name'] < $b['voter_meta']['name'])
     ? -1
     : 1;

 });
```